# What is the purpose of @NamedArg annotation in javaFX 8?

Tags: java, javafx, annotations

I would like to know what is the use case of @NamedArg annotation in JavaFX 8

The javadoc does not give us more details,
Javadoc : Annotation that provides information about argument's name.

And no more information, documentation, examples on the internet.

Maybe someone could help ?

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for this question. I wasn't aware of `@NamedArgs` until I saw this and researched an answer. I had been wondering how the issue with `FXMLLoader` relying on builders was going to be resolved when builders were removed, and this answers that question too.

Comment: For complete list of FXML annotations, have a look at http://abhinay.xyz/javafx/2018/05/09/FXML-friendly-custom-controls.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `@NamedArg` annotation allows an `FXMLLoader` to instantiate a class that does not have a zero-argument constructor.

**Technical Background:**

The `FXMLLoader` creates objects using reflection. Typically, if you use a tag corresponding to a class with a constructor taking no arguments, an object is created from that class by calling `Class.newInstance()`, which invokes the no-argument constructor.

If a class is defined only with constructors that take parameters, then this is problematic. The main issue is that the Java Language Specification does not require the names of parameters (to methods or constructors) to be retained at runtime. This means there's no direct, guaranteed, way for the `FXMLLoader` to determine which parameter has a given name.

To make this concrete, suppose we define a `Person` class as follows:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName ;
    private final StringProperty lastName ;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", lastName);
    }

    // methods....

}
```

In FXML we might try to create a `Person` as follows:

```
<Person firstName="Jacob" lastName="Smith"/>
```

This won't work, because the FXML loader has no guarantee that the runtime representation of the `Person` class retains the information as to which constructor parameter is `firstName` and which is `lastName`.

**Historical background**

Java 2.2 defined "Builder" classes corresponding to each control. These builder classes follow the standard builder pattern. When the `FXMLLoader` encounters a tag referencing a class with no zero-argument constructor, it would use the corresponding builder to create the instance.

Unfortunately, the implementation of the builder classes was flawed, and [they were deprecated in JavaFX 8](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html), and will be removed in a later version (probably JavaFX 9). This left a problem for the `FXMLLoader`, which would no longer have builder classes to rely on for instantiating classes with no zero-argument constructor. A real example is the [`Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) class, which has no zero-argument constructor and will have its builder class removed.

`@NamedArgs`

The fix for this was to introduce an annotation that is used to retain a name of a method (or constructor) argument at runtime. By reflection, we can query the parameter list of a constructor/method, and get the type (but not the name) of each parameter. It is also possible to query each parameter for any annotations, and get the value of those annotations. So the `@NamedArg` annotation was introduced specifically for the purpose of retaining a name of a parameter at runtime.

**Example**

For an example, use the `Person` class we introduced above:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName ;
    private final StringProperty lastName ;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", lastName);
    }

    public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() { return firstName; }
    public final String getFirstName() { return firstNameProperty().get(); }
    public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) { firstNameProperty().set(firstName); }
    public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() { return lastName; }
    public final String getLastName() { return lastNameProperty().get(); }
    public final void setLastName(final String lastName) { lastNameProperty().set(lastName); }
}
```

If you try to load this using FXML:

Person.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import application.Person?>
<Person firstName="Jacob" lastName="Smith" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

Main.java:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
        Person person = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("Person.fxml"));
        System.out.println(person.getFirstName()+" "+person.getLastName());
    }
}
```

then you see an error at runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: application.Person.<init>()
```

indicating the `FXMLLoader` is looking for a constructor taking no arguments (`Person.<init>()`).

In JavaFX 8, you can fix the problem by specifying the name of the parameters with the `@NamedArg` annotation:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName ;
    private final StringProperty lastName ;

    public Person(@NamedArg("firstName") String firstName, @NamedArg("lastName") String lastName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", lastName);
    }

    public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() { return firstName; }
    public final String getFirstName() { return firstNameProperty().get(); }
    public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) { firstNameProperty().set(firstName); }
    public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() { return lastName; }
    public final String getLastName() { return lastNameProperty().get(); }
    public final void setLastName(final String lastName) { lastNameProperty().set(lastName); }
}
```

This will allow the `FXMLLoader` to load the class as required.

Note that you can also fix the issue by defining a builder class, and that this also works in JavaFX 2.0 and later. The JavaFX team decided (probably correctly) that using this approach in a way that didn't suffer from the bugs that existed in the initial implementation of the builders would add too much bloat to the codebase of the framework.

```
package application;

public class PersonBuilder {

    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName ;

    private PersonBuilder() {   }

    public static PersonBuilder create() {
        return new PersonBuilder();
    }

    public PersonBuilder firstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName ;
        return this ;
    }

    public PersonBuilder lastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName ;
        return this ;
    }

    public Person build() {
        return new Person(firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

Clearly if you are using JavaFX 8, the constructor annotation approach is much less work.

**References:**

- [Proposal to deprecate builders](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html)
- [Tweak request to add constructor annotations](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-32860)
- [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)
- [FXML documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements) (discusses builders, but not `@NamedArg`)
- [Request to add documentation on @NamedArgs to "Introduction to FXML" document](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39329)

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete and illustrated answer, until now i had to define empty no-arg constructors for my JavaFX beans, it will change and cleanup my code with @NamedArg.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for your thorough explanation! Just curious, after more than 4 years, are `Builder` and `BuilderFactory` finally deprecated? And why `Request to add documentation on @NamedArgs to "Introduction to FXML" document` is marked as wontfix (makes me quite confused when reading the document)?