# Initialize Spinner control in fxml

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

New JDK is here:

> JDK 8u40 release includes new JavaFX UI controls; a spinner control, formatted-text support, and a standard set of alert dialogs.

I want to initiliaze the Spinner with an IntegerSpinnerValueFactory in fxml. I tried like the following:

```
<Spinner><valueFactory><SpinnerValueFactory ???????? /></valueFactory></Spinner>
```

There is little documentation for the new control and considering that is only java in class coding.

Any idea of how to initialize it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a look at the `Spinner` class, you have several constructors available.

For instance:

```
public Spinner(@NamedArg("min") int min,
               @NamedArg("max") int max,
               @NamedArg("initialValue") int initialValue) {
    this((SpinnerValueFactory<T>)new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(min, max, initialValue));
}
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26824088/3956070):

> The @NamedArg annotation allows an FXMLLoader to instantiate a class that does not have a zero-argument constructor.

so you can use `min`, `max` and `initialValue` as parameters for the `Spinner` on your FXML file:

```
<Spinner fx:id="spinner" min="0" max="100" initialValue="3" >
      <editable>true</editable>
</Spinner>
```

Note that your IDE may complain about it with warnings about `Class javafx.scene.control.Spinner doesn't support property 'min'`... But you can build and run the project.

Comment: Used it on my fxml like 

`<Spinner editable="true" min="0" max="100" initialValue="0"  />`

But it's not truly editable. It just returns to previous value before typing the desired value and using the increment/decrement arrows.

I will just keep using my custom control until I fully figure out how to achieve my desired behaviour with Spinner.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you can set `editable` inline, that's even better.