# Getting a custom class to be recognized as an fxml tag

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have a custom textfield, `PersistentPromptTextField` that extends `TextField` and would like to be able to add it my .fxml file. When I do and I run it, I get a list of errors such as this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: gui.PersistentPromptTextField
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: gui.PersistentPromptTextField.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
... 77 more
```

In my .fxml file I have included `<?import gui.PersistentPromptTextField?>` as well, but obviously I am missing something.

Comment: Try adding a no-arg constructor to PersistentPromptTextField.

Comment: @UlukBiy, that worked! Do you know how I could go about passing arguments to it? Like is it possible to make a custom tag `arg1` and `arg2` for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error raised due to the `FXMLLoader` is (by default) tried to instantiate the given class using its a no-arg constructor. If you didn't define, try it.

Instantiating using a constructor having some arguments, you need to use `@NamedArgs` annotation. See [this comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26824088) for more details.