# To use or not to use java FXML builders

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

We have started to use the java FX with FXML for a desktop application.
We need to load some combos with values from a local cache and we created a builder that instantiate the combo, fill it with values from cache and return it.
We expect to have around 20 builders.

I know most of java FX builders are deprecated because of this 
 http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html

According to a FXML tutorial if the `FXMLLoader` cannot create an object of a class, it looks for a builder that can create the object. A builder is an implementation of the `Builder` interface. The interface is in the `javafx.util` package and it contains one method `build()`.

I don’t see having the problems they have in the article and I know that if the java builders are deprecated doesn't mean changes in the FXMLLoader,  still I'm concerned having unexpected behaviors with the future releases of javaFX.

Given that we are at the beginning of the project should we continue to use the java fx builders?

Comment: Not entirely clear what the question is. If you are using the existing builder classes defined as part of the JavaFX libraries, then, no, you should not use those. They will be removed in a future version (if not already). If you are creating your own builder classes and specifying a builder factory on the FXML loader, then I think you are fine. However, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823157/what-is-the-purpose-of-namedarg-annotation-in-javafx-8. Maybe you don't need builders at all?

Comment: We were creating our own builder classes. Now we don't need the builders, we found another way to load the combos using binding expressions something like: <ComboBox fx:id="combo1" items="${cache.observablePersons}" /> and FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(...); loader.getNamespace().put("cache", new LocalCache()); and the LocalCache class provides observablePersons

Comment: I found @DanNick comment helpful, though I had some problems implementing it. For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321738/javafx-dynamically-load-combobox/44323120#44323120)