# Set custom FXML properties as parameters for custom javafx component

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I created custom component TableBlock. It consists of a Label and TableView. TableViewcan have, for example, from 1 to 1000 rows. Number of rows is defined by parameter "rowsFromPrefs" in FXML file. This parameter is needed for creation of TableView. TableView is fully created by JAva code, in fxml is just its tag and parameter with a number of rows.

As i know, when JavaFX constructs FXML component, it first calls constructor, then @FXML annotated fields, then starts initialize() method.

In my case when initialize() starts, variable rowsFromPrefs still is null! But, if i try to get the value of rowsFromPrefs  from other thread (not JavaFX-launcher), i see that it defined = "2" like it should be.

So i can`t understand at what moment Java assigns object paramters from FXML file. How can i pass parameter from fxml file to object when it is being created.

I saw @NamedArg annotation for constructor parameters. Is it the only one way of passing parameter when objects are creating?

> the controller can define an initialize() method, which will be called once on >an implementing controller when the contents of its associated document have >been completely loaded:

TableBlock.java

```
public class TableBlock extends VBox{
    @FXML
    private String rowsFromPrefs;
    @FXML
    private Label label;

public TableBlock() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new   FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TableBlock.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    this.table = createTable(rowsFromPrefs);
}

public String getRowsFromPrefs() {
    System.out.println("getRowsFromPrefs");
    return rowsFromPrefs;
}


public void setRowsFromPrefs(String rowsFromPrefs) {
    this.rowsFromPrefs = rowsFromPrefs;
}
```

}

TableBlock.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import ru.laz.model.controls.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import ru.laz.model.controls.tableblock.*?>


<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label text="Label" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

View.java

```
public class View extends Application {
Parent root = null;
private Scene scene;

@Override
    public void init() {
    try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));
            root.requestLayout();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

@Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
     scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480, Color.LIGHTGRAY);
     stage.show();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
    }

}
```

View.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import ru.laz.model.controls.tableblock.*?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TableBlock rowsFromPrefs="2" id="IDDQD"/>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that the `@FXML` annotation on `rowsFromPrefs` is serving no purpose. `@FXML` causes a value to be injected for the field when the FXML file for which the current object is the controller has an element with an `fx:id` attribute whose value matches the field name. Since `TableBlock.fxml` has no element with `fx:id="rowsFromPrefs"`, this annotation isn't doing anything.

When the `FXMLLoader` that is loading `View.fxml` encounters the `<TableBlock>` element, it creates a `TableBlock` instance by calling its constructor. Then it will set the values specified by the attributes. So your FXML element

```
<TableBlock rowsFromPrefs="2" id="IDDQD"/>
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
TableBlock tableBlock = new TableBlock();
tableBlock.setRowsFromPrefs("2");
tableBlock.setId("IDDQD");
```

Of course, the constructor for `TableBlock` just does what the code says to do: it creates a `FXMLLoader`, sets the root and controller for that `FXMLLoader`, and then calls `load()`. The load process for *that* `FXMLLoader` will set the `@FXML`-injected fields on the controller (the `TableBlock` object whose constructor is executing), and then call `initialize()`.

So `initialize()` is invoked as part of the call to `FXMLLoader.load()` that is in the `TableBlock` constructor; of course this all happens before `setRowsFromPrefs("2");` is invoked.

So in summary, `TableBlock.initialize()` is called after `TableBlock.fxml` has been parsed, and any elements defined there injected into their corresponding `@FXML`-annotated fields, but this happens before `View.fxml` has been loaded.

One way to fix this is to pass `rowsFromPrefs` to the `TableBlock` constructor. To do this, use the [`@NamedArg` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823157/what-is-the-purpose-of-namedarg-annotation-in-javafx-8):

```
public class TableBlock extends VBox{

    private final String rowsFromPrefs;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    public TableBlock(@NamedArg("rowsFromPrefs") String rowsFromPrefs) {

        this.rowsFromPrefs = rowsFromPrefs ;
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new   FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TableBlock.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        this.table = createTable(rowsFromPrefs);
    }

    public String getRowsFromPrefs() {
        System.out.println("getRowsFromPrefs");
        return rowsFromPrefs;
    }


}
```

Now your attribute in the FXML will be passed to the constructor instead of to a set method, so `rowsFromPrefs` will be initialized before you call `fxmlLoader.load()`, as required.

The other option, of course, would simply be to move the code from the `initialize()` method to the `setRowsFromPrefs(...)` method. I would use the option described above if you intend `rowsFromPrefs` to be fixed for each `TableBlock` instance, and use the second option only if you want to be able to change `rowsFromBlocks` during the lifecycle of an individual `TableBlock` instance.

Comment: thank you very much for detailed explanation. NamedArg is appropriate solution, as i think .