# passing objects as arguments using namedArg annotation in javafx 8

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, richtextfx

how do one pass a non-string object as argment using @namedArg in javafx? I cannot find a single nutshell example regarding this question online!

I am currently trying to instantiate a InlineCssTextArea from RichTextFX wrapped in a VirtualizedScrollPane - please have a look at this source code:

```
public VirtualizedScrollPane(@NamedArg("content") V content) {
  [...]
}
```

where the custom type V is extending Node. In my case, I want to pass InlineCssTextArea as V. Doing this programmatically is pretty easy:

```
InlineCssTextArea area = new InlineCssTextArea();
Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(new VirtualizedScrollPane<>(area)), 600, 400);
```

but translating that to FXML is quite challenging. I have already tried a few things, like fx:factory based on the official oracle fxml tutorial:

```
<VirtualizedScrollPane fx:factory="content">
  <InlineCssTextArea />
</VirtualizedScrollPane>
```

or how @namedArg suggests, as argument:

```
<VirtualizedScrollPane content="InlineCssTextArea" />
```

-or-

```
<VirtualizedScrollPane content="<InlineCssTextArea />" />
```

Is there a fxml solution for this problem?

my question is based on the the following answer from James D: [What is the purpose of @NamedArg annotation in javaFX 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823157/what-is-the-purpose-of-namedarg-annotation-in-javafx-8/26824088#26824088)

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to pass a value for an argument called `content`. The two ways to pass a value for an argument in FXML are as an attribute: `content="..."` or using a property element. Using an attribute only works if you can pass a string which the FXML loader knows how to convert to the appropriate value (i.e. if the value is a string or a primitive type), which isn't the case here. Using a property element you just nest an element whose name is the property name and nest the value inside it:

```xml
<VirtualizedScrollPane>
    <content>
        <InlineCssTextArea />
    </content>
</VirtualizedScrollPane>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this approach does not work. I get an error while loading the fxml file. [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]

Comment: @Adrian Actually: what is a `VirtualizedScrollPane` (which package is it in)? I can't find it the RichTextFX documentation.

Comment: thanks for looking into it!
here is the URL of the source code:
https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/flowless/VirtualizedScrollPane.java

Comment: Hmm. Well, it should work; I created a dummy `VirtualizedScrollPane` class with the same constructors and it worked fine, but it's not working with the jar file I downloaded from flowless. The addition of the `@FXML` is a recent change: I wonder if that change hasn't made it to the snapshot yet. How are you installing the dependency on flowless, and which version are you using?

Comment: Ahh alright, now I understand. I went through the source code of the flawless jar and did not find any namedArg annotations - apparently they did not make it to the build yet. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Adrian If you're feeling adventurous, you could try to build it yourself from the current source...