# How to pass parameters to a controller's constructor when using `<fx:include>`?

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml, fxmlloader

I am learning JavaFX, and I have come across an issue involving the instantiation of controllers that I can not seem to solve. Essentially, I am wondering if it is possible to do one of the following:

1. Pass a parameter to the constructor of the controller when including FXML with `<fx:include>`; or
2. Specify a custom controller instance to use when including an FXML file with `<fx:include>`.

Note that these issues are related. In fact, the reason I am asking about option (2) is because it would solve option (1).

---

**My Setup**

---

I have the following, "main" FXML file:

```xml
<!-- XML declaration, imports, etc. removed for brevity -->
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <!-- ... -->
    <center>
        <!-- Note that PageSwitcher is a custom control that is capable of switching between pages — you should be able to ignore it here. -->
        <PageSwitcher fx:id="mainPageSwitcher" currentPageIndex="0">
            <!-- ... -->
            <fx:include source="dashboard.fxml" fx:id="dashboard" />
        </PageSwitcher>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

It has an associated controller, `MainPaneController`. I won't display it here, but I can, if necessary.

You may have noticed that my main FXML file does not have an `fx:controller` attribute on its `BorderPane`, despite the fact that I said that it had an associated controller. This is because, rather than allowing the `FXMLLoader` to create a controller for me (and thus, leaving me with no way to pass parameters to the constructor of the controller class), I chose, when loading the main FXML page in my main application class (i.e. the class that extends Application), to create my own instance of the `MainPaneController` class. You can see the `start()` method of my main application class:

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader mainPaneLoader;
    MainPaneController mainPaneController;
    Parent mainPane;

    // Initialize the project manager.
    projectManager = new ProjectManager(primaryStage);

    // Initialize the main pane loader.
    mainPaneLoader = new FXMLLoader();

    // Initialize the main pane controller.
    mainPaneController = new MainPaneController(projectManager);

    // Load the main pane.
    mainPaneLoader.setController(mainPaneController);
    mainPaneLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(MAIN_PANE_FXML_PATH));
    mainPane = mainPaneLoader.load();

    Scene mainScene;

    // Create the main scene and add it to the primary scene.
    mainScene = new Scene(mainPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);

    // Initialize the primary stage.
    primaryStage.setTitle(APPLICATION_TITLE);

    // Show the primary stage.
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that the "project manager" object defined above and passed into the constructor of the main pane controller is actually the primary motivation behind this entire question; it is (in addition to being passed to the main controller) the object that I need to pass to the controller of the FXML file that I included into the main FXML file using `<fx:include>`.

Now, this approach of creating my own controller instance and giving it to the `FXMLLoader` works very well for me. It allows me to easily, without any messy reflection, pass parameters to the constructor of the controller. However, it only works when I have an `FXMLoader` object to give the controller instance to.

In the *other* case, where I include an FXML file from the main FXML file using `<fx:include>`, JavaFX creates the controller for me, providing no way for me to either (1) pass parameters to the controller's constructor, or (2) use my own controller instance.

---

**What I've Tried**

---

While researching this issue, I cam across [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655618/how-to-define-the-controller-of-an-fxincluded-form-at-runtime) which seemed to have at least some bearing on the issue. From it, I learned about `FXMLLoader.setControllerFactory()`, which seemed at first like it could solve this problem. However, in order to use it, I was forced to use some rather messy reflection to check if the type's constructor could accept my object, and then use *more* reflection to create the controller, all the while hoping that no errors were going to be thrown because of a loophole in my code. I was forced to concede that this was not going to work.

I have also experimented with, rather than passing my object to the constructor of the controller, setting the object on the controller *after* the controller has been initialized. However, this did not work well because I needed to use the object in my controller's `initialize()` method, which is called *before* I would set the object on the controller. This could potentially be worked around by adding *another* initialize method where any functionality requiring the object could be located, perhaps called `objectInitialized()`; but then I would have to add this method to every single controller that needs this functionality, and I would have to remember to call all these methods at some point. Also, I wanted the object to be a `final` field in the controller class; obviously, it can't be final if it needs to be set externally.

Lastly, I also considered the option that, for every FXML file that I need to include into the main FXML file, rather than including it in the FMXL, I could do it from the Java controller. This way I could create my own `FXMLLoader`, set my own controller instance on it, and thus, solve the problem. However, I would, if possible, much prefer to keep all the UI code in the FXML files.

---

**Summary**

---

In summary, I need a way to pass parameters to the constructor of my controller when using `<fx:include>`.

I realize that this is a long question and a somewhat complicated issue, so I really appreciate any help you can provide. Also, please let me know in the comments if I need to clarify anything or post additional code.

Thank you all for you help!
—Jacob

Comment: The only way I can think of that would work in this case would be using a `controllerFactory`. Afaik the controller factory is used for `FXMLLoader`s loading nested fxmls too.

Comment: Creation of controllers is essentially reflection-based, no matter how it happens. I think my answer to the question you linked is the only way to go here.

Comment: @Fabian, @James_D: Okay, I see. Do you think it would be a good approach to include the FXML from my Java controller instead (option (3) above, under What I've Tried)? At first, I kind of wanted to avoid that, but it seems like it might be the best option. I could even create a helper method to do this that I could use whenever I needed this functionality. Would that or using `setControllerFactory()` be better?

Comment: @JacobLockard That would work; I think I would still prefer the controller factory option; but your mileage may vary. Another thing you might consider is a dependency injection factory such as Spring or Guice; these will basically ensure the fields in your controllers are initialized as needed, but of course they have their own learning curve.

Comment: @James_D, I decided to go with including it from the controller (See Answer Below). Thank you for your help though; your comments really helped to clarify things for me and  give me new ideas for any future projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further consideration, I have decided to simply implement Option (3) in my question under "What I've Tried". Basically, instead of using `<fx:include>`, I decided that it would be easier, more flexible, and more future-proof to include any controllers that require parameters directly/manually from my Java code.

---

**Why?**

---

As I thought more about my issue, I realized that there was absolutely no way for me to pass a parameter to the constructor of my controller "from my FXML". After all, since the object I was trying to pass was defined in my Java code (the main application class), there was not going to be a way to use it in FXML. Thus, my entire perspective on the issue changed.

**Option 1**

After I re-evaluated my options, I considered just using `FXMLLoader.setControllerFactor()` after all; this approach was confirmed by James_D in the comments he posted on my question: since *all* controller instantiation happens through reflection, using reflection to pass my object to the controller wouldn't necessarily be as bad of an idea as I thought. In fact, it would probably work quite well.

However, while this would work well if all I needed to do was pass a *single* object to the controller, what if, for some of my controller, I wanted to pass *multiple* objects (and perhaps of different types)? Then the controller factory would grow rather unwieldy as I would have to check for *multiple* parameters of potentially different types, and then pass the correct ones.

In addition, what if I wanted to pass an object to a controller, not from the *application class*, where the controller factory is defined, but from somewhere else? For example, imagine that I had an application class, `MyApplication.java`, a "main" controller, `MainController.java`, and a controller "under" the main one, `NavigationBarController.java`? Perhaps I, at some point, would want to pass an object, not from *`MyApplication`* to `NavigationBarController`, but from *`MainController`* to `NavigationBarController`. If that was the case (which is quite possible), then my controller factory would no longer work because it would not have access to the necessary object. Thus, I concluded that `setControllerFactory()` would not work for me, at least not very well.

**Option 2 (What I Used)**

The other option (and the one I ended up using) was to include my controllers from my Java code, using `FXMLLoader` directly; and, rather then including all the controllers from the main application class, I could include each one in the *controller* that it "resided" in.

For example, using the example provided in Option (1) above, rather than using a controller factory and an `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file, I would remove the `fx:controller` attribute from any FXML file/controller pair that needed access to my object.

Instead, in `MyApplication` I would use `FXMLLoader` directly to load, initialize, and add `MainController`. Then, in `MainController`, I would use `FXMLLoader` to include `NavigationBarController`.

Now, the biggest potential weakness with this approach is the fact that I would need to basically repeat the loading code every time I wanted to include an FXML file/controller pair. To solve this, I created a sort of "utility class" called `FXMLQuickLoader` that contains methods to easily and quickly load FXML file/controller pairs, but with custom controller objects. If you are interested in seeing the code, I created a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/jacoblockard99/d2d15a541a4e80dcee0b3f1360a827a0) containing `FXMLQuickLoader.java`.

**Option 3 (Untested)**

Now, James_D pointed out that I could potentially use something called a "dependency injection factory". If I understood him correctly, it would automatically initialize my controllers' fields, rather than me needing to pass objects into constructors. This solution seems like it would work perfectly; however, because this is my first JavaFX project, and because I am under some time constraints, I decided that it would likely take too long to learn it.

However, for my next JavaFX project, I will probably look into it and (strongly) consider using it. I will try to update this answer later if I do.

---

**Summary**

---

In summary, for me, I determined that it would be best to include my controllers manually using `FXMLLoader`, rather than trying to use one of the alternatives. However, I am just learning JavaFX, and I am not exactly knowledgeable on the subject, so you should take this answer with a grain of salt. It may help other users who come along, though, and at least outline some *potential* solutions. I am also still open to further suggestions about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived implementing a singleton (or Bean in Spring), then every controller that wants to access the "shared" data just have to access singleton using getInstance method and then recover it.

It's more flexible if implemented with a Map<String, Object> property (instead  of User) and put data using put("key", objectValue) method, then using get("key");

Based on this [post](https://dev.to/devtony101/javafx-3-ways-of-passing-information-between-scenes-1bm8)

```
//Bean or Singleton
public final class UserHolder {

private User user;
private final static UserHolder INSTANCE = new UserHolder();

private UserHolder() {}

public static getInstance() {
  return INSTANCE;
}

public void setUser(User u) {
  this.user = u;
}

public User getUser() {
  return this.user;
}
}

//put data in Controller 1
@FXML
private void sendData(MouseEvent event) {
// Step 1
User u = new User();
Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
stage.close();
try {
  Parent root =     
  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/SceneB.fxml"));
  // Step 2
  UserHolder holder = UserHolder.getInstance();
  // Step 3
  holder.setUser(u);
  // Step 4
  Scene scene = new Scene(root);
  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println(String.format("Error: %s", e.getMessage()));
}
}

//recover data in Controller 2
@FXML
private void receiveData(MouseEvent event) {
  UserHolder holder = UserHolder.getInstance();
  User u = holder.getUser();
  String name = u.getName();
  String email = u.getEmail();
}
```