# Is it possible to refer to converters in JavaFX through FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm currently setting my converters (StringConverter) in the Controller, but I was wondering if it was possible to do it straight from the FXML file?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the converter and if getter+setter are available for the target property or a constructor with `@NamedArg` exists initializing the property.

Comment: Can you give me more details (as an answer) or direct me to what the keywords to search more about it? Google was not very helpful.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#class_instance_elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `FXMLLoader` instantiates types via reflection. This means the class must either have a constructor whose parameters are annotated with [`@NamedArg`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/NamedArg.html) or a constructor with zero parameters. The `@NamedArg` solves the issue of parameter names not necessarily being saved in the byte code, as better explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26824088/6395627). The remaining attributes will be set on the object according to the rules specified in [this section](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#property_elements) of *Introduction to FXML*. To summarize, the FXML attribute/element must have a corresponding property setter, read-only `List` property, or read-only `Map` property in the target class.

What this all means for your question is:

1. It depends on the implementation of `StringConverter`.

   - It must have a no-argument constructor or have `@NamedArg` annotated constructor parameters.
2. It depends on the object you're setting the `StringConverter` on.

   - It must either have a suitably annotated constructor parameter or the property must have a setter. Otherwise the FXML loader won't know how to set the converter.

Looking at the source code it doesn't look like any of the `StringConverter` implementations use the `@NamedArg` annotation. They often do provide a no-argument constructor, however. This will allow you to use them but you may lose the ability to customize them. For instance, when using `LocalDateStringConverter` you won't be able to customize the format.

That said, you could always create a factory class and use [`fx:factory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduc) in the FXML file.

```
public class Converters {

    public static StringConverter<LocalDate> myAwesomeConverter() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = ...;
        return new LocalDateStringConverter(formatter, formatter);
    }

}
```

```xml
<DatePicker>
    <converter>
        <Converters fx:factory="myAwesomeConverter"/>
    </converter>
</DatePicker>
```

Or if you don't want a custom formatter, you can just use the converter's no-arg constructor.

```xml
<DatePicker>
    <converter>
        <LocalDateStringConverter/>
    </converter>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great explanation! Now, from a more practical standpoint, do you guys in general do set the converters out of the FXML or just do it from the Controller?