# FXML - Prevent from using a property setter two times

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

My code (not actual code):

Base.java

```
public class Base extends Parent {

    public final void setPanel(HBox value) {
        //some code
    }

    public final HBox getPanel() {
        //some code
        return null;
    }

}
```

Main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import sample.Base?>
<Base xmlns:fx="gui" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <panel>
        <HBox>
            <Region/>
        </HBox>
    </panel>
    <panel>
        <HBox>
            <Pane/>
        </HBox>
    </panel>
</Base>
```

As you can see, I'm able to call setPanel(HBox) twice. I'm talking about FXML. Is there any way I can prevent from sitautions like that? Is there any way to set the thing up so I can get an error when trying to do so?

PS. I know I can check for second call in the setPanel(HBox) function, but I'm just curious if I can prevent from calling it second time in FXML code.

Comment: You can make it a final field, and define a constructor which initializes it instead of a `set` method. Annotate the constructor parameter with [`@NamedArg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823157/what-is-the-purpose-of-namedarg-annotation-in-javafx-8)

Comment: @James_D assuming` @NamedArg("pane") Pane pane` in the constructor of `Base` how do we assign an HBox instance to it (`<Base pane = "?">`) keeping `Base` a `Parent` ?

Comment: @James_D That kind of works. I'm able to put <panel> tag twice, but only the first one is used in the constructor, the second one is just ignored

Comment: @ImNotARobot consider posting an answer