# Using extended custom class from FXML with custom ControllerFactory

Tags: user-interface, javafx, model-view-controller, fxml

I want to embed my own custom controls that extend from other controls. I want to extend them within Java via extends, not from FXML via fx:root type="..."! As I want to use MVC pattern I use a custom ControllerFactory so that models can be passed to constructors of my controls (see **AppStarter.java**). In this simple example AppStarter.java loads **container.fxml** that includes two TextFields. These are bound to my model that is passed to them by ControllerFactory. If text is typed in 'textFieldIn' the model is updated and output will be displayed in 'textFieldOut'.

This works fine but I am not able to use a control that extends from another control. I extended TextField (see ExtendedTextField.java) and tried to embed it in fxml (see **container.fxml**) and got a **"unable to instantiate**"-error.

How can I solve this problem?

**AppStarter.java**

```
public class AppStarter extends Application {

    private Model model;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.model = new Model("model data (string)");
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/container.fxml"));

            fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory((Class<?> type) -> {
                try {
                    for (Constructor<?> c : type.getConstructors()) {
                        if (c.getParameterCount() == 1 && c.getParameterTypes()[0] == Model.class) {
                            return c.newInstance(model);
                        }
                    }
                    // default behavior: invoke no-arg constructor:
                    return type.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(exc);
                }
            });

            root = fxmlLoader.load();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**container.fxml**

```
<SplitPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <Pane>
        <fx:include source="textFieldIn.fxml" fx:id="textFieldIn"/>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
        <fx:include source="textFieldOut.fxml" fx:id="textFieldOut"/>
        <!-- <ExtendedTextField/> **HERE I WANT TO EMBED MY EXTENDED CONTROL INSTEAD** -->
    </Pane>
</SplitPane>
```

**textFieldIn.fxml**

```
<TextField xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
           fx:controller="gui.TextFieldInController" fx:id="textFieldIn">
</TextField>
```

**textFieldOut.fxml**

```
<TextField xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
           fx:id="textFieldOut" fx:controller="gui.TextFieldOutController">
</TextField>
```

**ExtendedTextField.java**

```
public class ExtendedTextField extends TextField {
    public ExtendedTextField(Model model) {
        this.setText("ExtendedTextField");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not tested, but try making the constructor parameter a [`@NamedArg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823157/what-is-the-purpose-of-namedarg-annotation-in-javafx-8) and passing `model=“${controller.model}”` from the FXML. You may need to add a `getModel()` method to the controller, if you don’t already have one.

Comment: @James_D: Thx for your advice! Unfortunately I did not fully understand. I added "@NamedArg("model") Model model" to constructor of ExtendedTextField. But when I try to address my model via "model="${ExtendedTextFieldController.model}" or model="${AppStarter.model} answer is "Cannot resolve symbol ...". From FXML documentation it seems as if addressing is only possible if there is a control/tag with an according fx:id within the same fxml document.

Comment: Try it like I suggested: `model=“${controller.model}”` The controller is automatically placed into the FXMLLoader namespace (with key “controller”). If your controller class has a `getModel()` method, `${controller.model}` should resolve to that.

Comment: Another possibility is to do `fxmlLoader.getNamespace(“model”, model)` (before calling `fxmlLoader.load()`). Then in FXML just use `model=“${model}”`.

Comment: I also tried it with: model=“${controller.model}” now but still get "Cannot resolve symbol..." My ExtendedTextFieldController.java has a getModel() method.

Comment: I don’t understand where you are seeing that error message. “Can not resolve symbol” is a compile error. FXML is not compiled.

Comment: I also tried "fxmlLoader.getNamespace().put("model", model);" and "<ExtendedTextField model="${model}"/>" but he does not finds symbol and guves me "javafx.fxml.LoadException: Cannot bind to untyped object."

Comment: IntelliJ gives me "Cannot resolve symbol" when I put mouse over "model". It is also marked red. Usually ItelliJ marks everything in green when it finds something.

Comment: Hmm. It seems as though expression bindings are not parsed for constructor arguments. So I don't really see a way to do this with a constructor parameter; you'd need to make the model a JavaFX Property. Note that you're really fighting against the API here, instead of working with it. JavaFX with FXML is based around a model-view-presenter (also called "Passive View") pattern, not the traditional MVC pattern.

Comment: Ok, I am willing to try something different as I can not get it work. Can you give me a good starting point/thread for MVP that meets my demands?

Comment: All you need to do is pass the model to the controller class (as you already do), but the view (eg the text field) shouldn’t have a reference to the model (so there’s not even a need to subclass `TextField`). Just create the bindings between the model and the controls in the “controller” (which is really a presenter).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your support and for your patience, James! I tried but did not succed. 1. When I try to bind my TextField to the model in the construcor I get a NullPointerException because I can not reference TextField. Therefore I stored the reference to the model and did the binding in the initialize() method afterwards. (2) I do not understand why this relates to the extended TextField I want  to embed in FXML. My problem is still I can not get a reference to the model from the ExtendedTextfield so that I can bind it.

Comment: What I am saying is that the `ExtendedTextField` *should not have a reference to the model*. Based on the code you posted, that means there's no need to subclass `TextField` at all; just use a regular `TextField`. Then, as you say, just bind the text field's text property to a property in the model (or any other bindings you need) in the `initialize()` method. That's basically an exact implementation of the MVP pattern.

Comment: If you try to force JavaFX + FXML into a MVC pattern instead of the intended MVP pattern, you're going to end up with all kinds of hacks that are going to be difficult to implement and maintain (if you can do it at all). Don't fight the API: use it the way it's intended.

Comment: Thanks, you encourage me! But what I do if I want to embed a class that extends another one? In this example I only extended TextField to see if it is possible to pass a model to an extended Control. This is because I have extended a Canvas (in Java) in one of my projects. And I want to embed it via FXML. But the class loader does not want to pass the model to it. Isnt it possible? Should I use composition instead of inheritance then?

Comment: It will work as long as any parameters you pass to the constructor can be determined easily in FXML (i.e. via string values, but not via expression binding, as far as I can tell). The problem is "passing a model to a canvas" violates the MVP pattern, because your canvas is a view class, and should not have access to the model in that design. You could play with `<fx:reference>` perhaps, but again your code will get ugly quickly...